# How to realise a pub/sub alert system with Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, alert, monitoring, publish-subscribe

I am new to monitoring with Prometheus and Grafana. At the moment we can configure an alert channel to send emails when critical events occur. But in our requirement we need to publish to a pub/sub topic to communicate with other components of the system, because we use grafana as a rules repository and we need to automate some actions in the related monitored components when alerts are triggered. Is there a way to do this in grafana? If not, how can I best implement this requirement? Any suggestions are welcome.

The first idea I have is to write a programme to query Prometheus metrics and do pub/sub notification in relation to rules (which are dynamics). But I am afraid of reinventing the wheel and it may take a lot of time to implement from scratch.

Comment: Don't configure email notification, but use webhook. Your code, which will create event in your pub/sub infrastructure will be behind that webhook.

Comment: The disadvantage of calling a hook instead of performing a pub/sub directly (if it were possible) is that it adds more latency to the comminucation time.

Comment: I agree. But there is no pub/sub contact point type. I wish to have AWS EventBridge https://github.com/grafana/grafana/discussions/70288 so I would have nice event driven architecture. You can make you hand dirty and you can code pub/sub contact point type. I believe if you have good code, then it will be merged.